# Flutter, how to using square brackets to access dynamic key of list

Tags: flutter

When I use https://dartpad.dev/?id

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final matches = [
  {
    "match_id": 6604501658,
    "player_slot": 129,
    "radiant_win": false,
    "duration": 2020,
    "game_mode": 22,
    "lobby_type": 7,
    "hero_id": 19,
    "start_time": 1654520510,
    "version": 21,
    "kills": 13,
    "deaths": 7,
    "assists": 17,
    "skill": null,
    "xp_per_min": 780,
    "gold_per_min": 604,
    "hero_damage": 36271,
    "tower_damage": 10042,
    "hero_healing": 0,
    "last_hits": 211,
    "lane": 2,
    "lane_role": 2,
    "is_roaming": false,
    "cluster": 156,
    "leaver_status": 0,
    "party_size": 1
  },
  {
    "match_id": 6604451816,
    "player_slot": 4,
    "radiant_win": false,
    "duration": 1242,
    "game_mode": 22,
    "lobby_type": 7,
    "hero_id": 52,
    "start_time": 1654518740,
    "version": 21,
    "kills": 7,
    "deaths": 4,
    "assists": 1,
    "skill": null,
    "xp_per_min": 540,
    "gold_per_min": 472,
    "hero_damage": 14678,
    "tower_damage": 2111,
    "hero_healing": 0,
    "last_hits": 136,
    "lane": 2,
    "lane_role": 2,
    "is_roaming": false,
    "cluster": 156,
    "leaver_status": 0,
    "party_size": 1
  }
];
  final List<String> extraList = ['kills','deaths','assists','gold_per_min','xp_per_min','last_hits','hero_damage','hero_healing','tower_damage','duration'];
  for(var i in extraList) {
    print(averMax(matches, i));
  }
}


String averMax(dynamic matches, String field) {
    final dynamic matchesMap = matches.map((match) => match[field]);
    final dynamic matchesReduce = matchesMap.reduce((cur, total) => cur + total);
        return field != 'duration' ?
            greaterNum((matchesReduce / 20).round(), 1000, 'K') :
          (matchesReduce / 20).toString();
}
String greaterNum(double num, int gN, String unit)  {
        var minus = '';
    if (num < 0) {
      minus = '-';
    }
    num = (num).abs();
    if (num > gN) {
      final newNum = (num / gN).toStringAsFixed(1);
      return '$minus$newNum$unit';
    } else {
      return '$minus$num';
    }
}
```

Works

However at flutter:
Flutter the PlayerMatches is from API which is List
I want to map the extraList value as key in the matches to dynamic get data and pass to a List View

In dartPad works, however in flutter cant access data use square brackets.
[image]

My question:
Could I access the Object key dynamically like javascript?

Thanks for @lepsch who help me

At flutter,

```
return match.toJson()[field];
```

Comment: Seems like dartPad link is broken , can you provide necessary snippet? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Sorry for incomplete copy code, here we go.

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter doesn't support reflection/mirrors](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflection--mirrors-system) so it's not possible to get a property by name. This is on purpose so Flutter knows at compile time all kinds of access to an object that exists and can optimize it accordingly by tree-shaking (*Strip out anything that isn’t used*).

One solution could be converting `PlayerRecentMatch` to JSON as a `Map<String, dynamic>`. This way you can access the `Map` with the brackets operator.

Another way though to implement your function is using a first-class function as an argument to get the property instead of the property name. Take a look below:

```dart
class PlayerRecentMatch {
  final double score;
  const PlayerRecentMatch({required this.score});  
}

double averMax(
  List<PlayerRecentMatch> matches,
  double Function(PlayerRecentMatch) getProperty, // <- Here
) {
  final matchesMap = matches.map((match) { 
    return getProperty(match);
  }).toList();
  final matchesReduce = matchesMap.reduce((sum, total) => sum + total);
  return matchesReduce / matches.length;
}

void main() {
  final matches = [
    PlayerRecentMatch(score: 1),
    PlayerRecentMatch(score: 2),
    PlayerRecentMatch(score: 3),
    PlayerRecentMatch(score: 4),
  ];
  print('averMax = ${averMax(matches, (match) => match.score)}');
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/?id=44cbecffd6f86f1714a4553101a16001

Comment: That is okay, however,  I wanna the score as a dynamic varaible.  final List<String> extraList = ['kills','deaths','assists','gold_per_min','xp_per_min','last_hits','hero_damage','hero_healing','tower_damage','duration'];  then I could access match[extraListField] rather than math.kills, match.deaths

Comment: If `PlayerRecentMatch` comes from an API it most probably has the `toJson` method. If so, you can transform the `PlayerRecentMatch` object to JSON first and then access its fields with brackets. It works because the transformed JSON is a `Map<String, dynamic>` in the same way your minimal-reproducible-example does.

Comment: Thanks for the very very hint which suffer me long time. Now I use return match.toJson()[field]; I could access the dynamic key